# Query internal stage Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, staging

Following the steps in the documentation I created a stage and a file format in Snowflake, then staged a csv file with PUT

```
USE IA;
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE csv_format_2;
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT csvcol26 type='csv' field_delimiter='|';
PUT file://H:\\CSV_SWF_file_format_stage.csv @IA.public.csv_format_2
```

When I tried to query the staged object

```
SELECT a.$1 FROM @csv_format_2 (FORMAT=>'csvcol26', PATTERN=>'CSV_SWF_file_format_stage.csv.gz') a
```

I got:
SQL Error [2] [0A000]: Unsupported feature 'TABLE'.

Any idea on this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument should be `FILE_FORMAT` instead of `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT a.$1 
FROM @csv_format_2 (FILE_FORMAT=>'csvcol26',PATTERN=>'CSV_SWF_file_format_stage.csv.gz') a;
```

Related: [Querying Data in Staged Files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html)

> Query staged data files using a SELECT statement with the following syntax:
>
> ```
> SELECT [<alias>.]$<file_col_num>[.<element>] [ , [<alias>.]$<file_col_num>[.<element>] , ...  ]
> FROM { <internal_location> | <external_location> }
>  [ ( FILE_FORMAT => '<namespace>.<named_file_format>', PATTERN => '<regex_pattern>' ) ]
>  [ <alias> ]
> ```

Comment: The reason the TABLE message is thrown is because file format argument is within a TABLE OPERATOR on SELECT.   Since the name of the argument isn't recognized as a legal operator you get this potentially confusing response.